# Push an element into an array if a field satisfies a condition, MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following structure:

```json
"roles": [
  {
    "aspirants": ["Will Smith"],
    "description": {
      "content": "Role 1 content",
      "title": "Role 1"
    },
    "quantity": 12,
    "remunaration": 950
  },
  {
    "aspirants": ["Bruce Wayne"],
    "description": {
      "content": "Role 2 content",
      "title": "Role 2"
    },
    "quantity": 6,
    "remunaration": 1000
  }
]
```

So, what I need to do is to add a new aspirant matching the role he is postulating (that data is coming from the UI). For example, if "Tony Stark" is postulating to the "Role 1", then I have to update that field, so it will end as follows:

```json
"roles": [
  {
    "aspirants": ["Will Smith", "Tony Stark"],
    "description": {
      "content": "Role 1 content",
      "title": "Role 1"
    },
    "quantity": 12,
    "remunaration": 950
  },
  {
    "aspirants": ["Bruce Wayne"],
    "description": {
      "content": "Role 2 content",
      "title": "Role 2"
    },
    "quantity": 6,
    "remunaration": 1000
  }
]
```

Any idea how can I achieve this? Of course, the roles are a field from a document.

Comment: Have you tried anything from [Array Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/update-array/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use with `arrayFilters`

```
db.collection.update(
    {},
    {$addToSet:{'roles.$[r].aspirants':"Spider man"}},
    { arrayFilters: [{ 'r.description.title': 'Role 1' }], new: true }
)
```